Save World.Environement into config.yml
I want have a lobby world.
I want this lobby world can be change in the config.yml.
To load this world, I need to use the command:
WorldCreator lobby = new WorldCreator("MyLobbyWorldName");
Bukkit.createWorld(lobby);

Problem, my current lobby is in the end. So I need to do this:
WorldCreator lobby = new WorldCreator("MyLobbyWorldName");
lobby.environment(World.Environment.THE_END);
Bukkit.createWorld(lobby);

So to put this in my config.yml, I need to put "MyLobbyWorldName" and "World.Environment.THE_END" in my config.yml.
I can put "MyLobbyWorldName" in the config.yml easily.
WorldCreator lobby = new WorldCreator(getConfig().getString("lobby.world.name"));
lobby.environment(World.Environment.THE_END);
Bukkit.createWorld(lobby);

But I don't now how to formulate the "World.Environment.THE_END" in the config.yml file and how to put it back in the code. Now I have that:
WorldCreator lobby = new WorldCreator(getConfig().getString("lobby.world.name"));
lobby.environment((World.Environment) getConfig().get("lobby.world.environement"));
Bukkit.createWorld(lobby);

but I have an "org.bukkit.configuration.InvalidConfigurationException: could not determine a constructor for the tag tag:yaml.org,2002:org.bukkit.World$Environment
in 'string', line 9, column 19:
environement: !!org.bukkit.World$Environment ' ..." error.

environement is misspelled, additionally, what is the value within the config.yml?

I try with "org.bukkit.World.Environment.THE_END" but it is not working. It tell me he can't transform a string into an Environment. I tried use getConfig().set("lobby.world.environement", World.Environement.THE_END) and saveCongig() but it dont work and give the error right above. By the way, "environement" is not a misspelling, I wrote it in French and never change it because it don't work.

In the config, it's easy to manage enum as World.Environment :

Use myEnum.name() to put in config with getConfig().set("lobby.world.environement", lobby.environment().name())
Get from THE_END with World.Environment.valueOf(getConfig().getString("lobby.world.environement"))

With that, you will only have simple string in config. Before using Enum#valueOf, you can check if it exists or try/catch for exception if user entered wrong input.
